# AttributeError: module XX has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, selenium

Python 3.7.2 Shell
Tried this;

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.opera
url="https://www.google.com"
browser.get(url)
```

Get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>
    browser.get(url)
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver.opera' has no attribute 'get'
```

Tried browser firefox got same error message.

Comment: Have you checked out the documentation? https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/blob/master/docs/desktop.md

Comment: I got code from here. http://stanford.edu/~mgorkove/cgi-bin/rpython_tutorials/Scraping_a_Webpage_Rendered_by_Javascript_Using_Python.php

Comment: Did you follow the instructions to download and install the Chromedriver: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver

Comment: I downloaded opera driver here. https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases

Answer (score 0):

Try this for Opera:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Opera()
url = "http://google.com"
browser.get(url)
```

Try this for Firefox:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
url = "http://google.com"
browser.get(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do following things and check whether it works.
Upgrade python bindings using

```
pip install -U selenium
```

for chrome browser download the latest chrome driver "ChromeDriver 2.45"
and write the below code

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser=webdriver.Chrome("Path of the Download Chromedriver" + "chromedriver.exe" )
url="https://www.google.com"
browser.get(url)
```

Comment: pip install -U selenium gives me:
Requirement already up to date.

Comment: Have you down loaded the chrome driver and tried above code?